# Why the HTML5 <audio> not working in Safari web browser?

Tags: html, audio, safari

I had implemented the HTML5 audio in the background on the following web site:
https://praxishelena.ch

When I open the web site, or when I click on a link, I can hear music on my Windows PC, and on Android device using Chrome, but on IPhone using Safari, not.
I was implementing music, using the following:

```
<audio src="wp-content/uploads/foldername/filename.mp3" style="display: none;" autoplay loop />
```

I need music in background without controlls for stopping, pausing, and volume change.
How to enable this to work in Safari?

Best regards,

Darko

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<audio>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/media.html#the-audio-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification (and neither do any other HTML tags).

Answer (score 0):

Certain HTML functions work differently or don't work on certain versions of certain browsers. Try checking what version it is using. Normally, Safari should support MP3 files. It only doesn't support .ogg files.